# Finding MLE based only on first r order statistics

Tags: maximum-likelihood, order-statistics

My question is in relation to finding the MLE of a sample from an exponential distribution, $exp(\theta)$, but based only on the first r order statistics. I can find the MLE of an exponential distribution by normal methods without a problem but am unsure of how basing the MLE on only the first r order statistics should change my approach.

I have made various attempts to start the question but haven't gotten very far. I have found the distribution of the first order statistic to be $exp(\theta / n)$ but am unsure if this is necessary or relevant.

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Proceed as usual: write down the joint probability density of all $r$ order statistics.  Maximize it with respect to $\theta$.

Comment: Hint: consider the $n$ r.vs of the sample as lifetimes and remind of
the *lack of memory* property of the exponential.  The first order
statistic is the arrival time of the first failure; when this occurs
there remains $n-1$ ``new'' individuals.